# RTL alignment in itextsharp c#

Tags: c#, itext

I want to add Arabic text to my pdf. I need to do an RTL alignment. [Hebrew text in PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130470/hebrew-text-in-pdf) gives the answer how to do using PdfpTable.

And using

```
table.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;
```

I can do that. But is there any other way to do so, when I am not creating a PdfPTable at all?

Comment: I would sugest you not using itextsharp. I would suggest you using wkhtmltopdf in which you can create a html to look as you want and to use that one; any setting you will do in your html(including css) will be `translated` to pdf. That's just my opinion. We used itextsharp and dumped it cause of it's limitations.

Comment: @HellBaby Thanks. I will definitely consider your suggestion. But for now i need to know this one. it would be nice if you can help.

Comment: according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7048709/1707033 you can set it on a element which is added to the document.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ColumnText` and set `RunDirection` of it to `RUN_DIRECTION_RTL`:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace iTextSharpTests
{
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           using (var pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4))
           {
               var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream("Test.pdf", FileMode.Create));
               pdfDoc.Open();

               var fontPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot") + "\\fonts\\tahoma.ttf";
               var baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
               var tahomaFont = new Font(baseFont, 10, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);

               ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(pdfWriter.DirectContent);
               ct.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;
               ct.SetSimpleColumn(100, 100, 500, 800, 24, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);

               var chunk = new Chunk("تست", tahomaFont);

               ct.AddElement(chunk);
               ct.Go();
           }
       }
   }
}
```